# Windows 10 is missing copy button in previous versions dialog. Any way to restore?

Tags: file-recovery, windows-10-v1703

In windows 8 and 7 (at least) it's possible to copy a previous file version, instead of overwriting the old one:

[image: Windows 7 with copy button]

In Windows 10 this button ist gone:

[image: Windows 10 (german)]

In my version (1703 Build 15063.413 German) the arrow next to the button text doesn't offer any other options (clicking does nothing, maybe a bug?). Is there any other way to directly copy an older version to a folder?

Comment: It behaves somewhat like a regular file view. You should be able to right-click and copy as well as use Ctrl+C. I don’t have any previous versions, so I cannot verify.

Answer (score 0):

As [Daniel B](https://superuser.com/users/219095/daniel-b) pointed out it's possible to copy the file directly from the dialog. [CTRL]+C didn't work for me, but using the context menu by right-clicking.